# WPF - How to get the URI Source of an Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, uri, bitmapframe

I want to get the URI Source of an image that has been created in XAML. The source of the image is a BitmapFrame. I know you can use BitmapImage.UriSource for BitmapImages, but what about BitmapFrames?

To get the BitmapFrame I use:

```
    private void imgs_Loaded(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = (Image)sender;
        BitmapFrame frame = (BitmapFrame)img.Source;
        //How to get frame's UriSource?
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the [BaseUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe.baseuri.aspx) property? And how do you create a BitmapFrame in XAML?

Comment: A URI may point to an image, but an image can exist without a URI. You may be better off recording a mapping of each image object to a URI earlier on when the images are created, and then looking up the URI from this list based on the image you get in the event handler.